# Python indexing numpy array using a smaller boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

> If obj.ndim == x.ndim, x[obj] returns a 1-dimensional array filled
>   with the elements of x corresponding to the True values of obj. The
>   search order will be row-major, C-style. If obj has True values at
>   entries that are outside of the bounds of x, then an index error will
>   be raised. If obj is smaller than x it is identical to filling it with
>   False.

I read from the numpy reference that I can index a larger array using a smaller boolean array ,and the rest entries would be automatically filled with False.

> Example :
>   From an array, select all rows which sum up to less or equal two:

```
>>> x = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
>>> rowsum = x.sum(-1)
>>> x[rowsum <= 2, :] 
array([[0, 1],[1, 1]])
```

> But if rowsum would have two dimensions as well:

```
>>> rowsum = x.sum(-1, keepdims=True)
>>> rowsum.shape 
(3, 1)
>>> x[rowsum <= 2, :]    # fails 
IndexError: too many indices
>>> x[rowsum <= 2] 
array([0, 1])
```

> The last one giving only the first elements because of the extra
>   dimension.

But the example simply doesn't work ,it says "IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1"

How to make it work ?I'm using python 3.6.3 and numpy 1.13.3.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Numpy 11, It's not compatible with the new default behaviour : ([boolean-indexing-changes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#boolean-indexing-changes)) :

> Boolean indexing changes.
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - Boolean indexes must match the dimension of the axis that
>   they index.
> - ...

Internals have been optimized, the docs not yet ....

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is NumPy broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
rowsum = x.sum(axis=1)
x[rowsum <= 2]
```

Gives:

```
array([[0, 1],
   [1, 1]])
```

The problem is that you used `keepdims=True`, which means the sum creates a column vector, rather than a rank one array which can be broadcasted.

Comment: This sample code is directly from the numpy documentation ,so is the documentation wrong about this ?

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug in the documentation!